# SonarQube calculates wrong code coverage from jacoco result

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

We have a java project for which we are using jenkins.
In the build part we have configured jacoco as java agent to measure the code coverage.

If I download the created jacoco report and load it to IntelliJ all is fine.
But the sonar scanner also loads it up to the sonar server and there is something wrong with the analysis: Some classes and methods which are covered by tests (and I can see the coverage from the jacoco report in IntelliJ) are reported as uncovered by SonarQube.

Sonar Scanner definitly handles the right jacoco report.

Has anybody any idea where I should look for?
Is there anything in the sonar server which can led to a wrong coverage?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sonar will look at code lines % coverage, not the same as IntelliJ's approach.

Comment: thank you for your comment. But SonarQube also shows which lines are covered and there are lines marked as uncovered which are definitly covered.

Comment: Are you sure that your tests do cover all the branches, conditions that could make part of those lines uncovered?

Comment: Yes, if I load the jacoco report file to IntelliJ it will be marked green for covered

Comment: Same problem here, the difference is 7% vs. 18%. It seems the reason is that the Sonar (7.4) now counts only coverage on lines in the same module as tests. Coverage in other modules is ignored. The extreme difference here is because I have integration tests in separated module - and results are completely ignored by SonarQube, I can see coverage only in Eclipse.

Comment: I am having same issue. Jacoco report when opened in IDE shows covered lines but SonarQube shows as uncovered even if tests are shown running successfully on SonarQube. Any idea why so?